# How to loop through an EntrySet within a HashMap loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, hashmap

I have a HashMap called "virtuosoMap" with the following structure:

```
{facebook=[[1, 22, 333], [4444, 55555, 66666]], twitter=[[1, 22, 333], [4444, 55555, 66666], [7777777, 22, 55555], [55555, 666666, 22]]}
```

I'm trying loop through this map and obtain the first numerical values of each `long[] Array` (i.e. 1 and 4444 for facebook), but I get stuck with the following error in Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [J at...
```

This is what I've coded so far:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<long[]>> virtuosoMapSingle : virtuosoMap.entrySet()) {
   for (long[] virtuosoMapSingleNumbers : virtuosoMapSingle.getValue()) {
      System.out.println(virtuosoMapSingleNumbers.get(0));
   }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which line, *exactly*, is causing the error?

Comment: the error comes from the second line in this example: "for (long[] virtuosoMapSingleNumbers : virtuosoMapSingle.getValue()) {"

Comment: @kiner_shah I could but I feel the rest of the code isn't really relevant to this example.

Comment: Arrays don't have a `get` method.

Comment: @Andrevin the error doesn't actually come from that line, but from the line above. But your point has been noted.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you are getting a `ClassCastException`. Your code runs fine here: http://ideone.com/JBQAya

Comment: Show us how you initialize `virtuosoMap`.  The rest of the code _is_ relevant; there's a bug _there,_ not in the code you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<long[]>> virtuosoMapSingle : virtuosoMap.entrySet()) {
   for (long[] virtuosoMapSingleNumbers : virtuosoMapSingle.getValue()) {
      System.out.println(virtuosoMapSingleNumbers[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Oops, so I didn't read the comment that already addressed this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this line `System.out.println(virtuosoMapSingleNumbers.get(0))`. The type of `virtuosoMapSingleNumbers` is actually `long[]` and `Array` doesn't have `get` method. Instead `virtuosoMapSingleNumbers[0]` should be used. By fixing that line you will solve your problem.

However `java-8` provides a new way of interacting with various collections - `Stream API`. The same code could be rewritten using `Streams`:

```
virtuosoMap.entrySet().stream().
            flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()).
            forEach(e -> System.out.println(e[0]));
```

Answer (score -1):

The List obviously doesn't contain array but another list. You need to change the type:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<List<Long>>> virtuosoMapSingle : virtuosoMap.entrySet()) {
    for (List<Long> virtuosoMapSingleNumbers : virtuosoMapSingle.getValue()) {
      System.out.println(virtuosoMapSingleNumbers.get(0));
     }
}
```

And of course the type of `virtuosoMap` must be changed to `Map<String, List<List<Long>>>`

Comment: Did you try the code? I get a Type mismatch error on the first line "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map.Entry<String,List<long[]>> to Map.Entry<String,List<List<Long>>>"

Comment: @TheBigDoubleA : Did you read the last part of the answer? The variable obviously contains something different than what it looks its declaration.